# How to determine where IP is Classful or Classless?

Tags: networking, subnet

e.g 200.1.10.12/24 is given, is it classful or classless?

I think it is classful but if CIDR is given does that mean it is classless?

also 200.1.10.12/25 , i think this is also classful with 2 subnets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addresses themselves are neither classful nor classless, it's about how a system uses them.

> e.g 200.1.10.12/24 is given, is it classful or classless?

"Classful" routing used to determine the netmask implicitly, based on the initial bits of the address itself. (This is no longer done anywhere at all.) For example, any 200.x.x.x address used to au­to­mat­i­cal­ly be class C with 24-bit network part.

So if a route or address range is specified together with a prefix length (like "/24") or with a subnet mask (like "255.255.255.0"), then it's classless just because of that. The /24 only *happens to match* the previously used class size, but that doesn't make it classful.

(And when a route *isn't* specified together with a prefix length, it's much more common to assume a full-length 'host' route e.g. /32 or /128 these days, although *some* old systems still assume a class-based route.)

Answer (score 1):

200.1.10.12/24 is a class C IP address and a classless address with a CIDR mask of /24. If an address is Classful then it's also Classless under CIDR, the inverse isn't always true.

Generally speaking:

- Class A -> /8
- Class B -> /16
- Class C -> /24

Comment: eg 200.1.10.12/25 , i think this is also classful with 2 subnets? or by default there is no subnets, we have to create upon requirement? am i right? so then it ll be classless?

Comment: It isn't classful. Generally classfullness is a thing of the past. We allocate IP addresses nowadays based on CIDR prefixes. I don't understand the thing you're saying with the 2 subnets. You must have misunderstood something. 200.1.10.12/25 has the network address: 200.1.10.0 , subnet mask: 255.255.255.128, broadcast address: 200.1.10.127 and can hold up to 126 hosts ( 200.1.10.1 - 200.1.10.126 )

Comment: 200.1.10.12/25 if i divide this address space into 2 parts..then it ll  be something 200.1.10.12/26 etc. now my question is if i have been given question to determine 200.1.10.12/26 is network or subnet?

Comment: You have a big mess on head right now...I suggest you see some tutorials or study a little more and come back.

Comment: @shivaniverma6991: There's no practical difference between the two, except at the very last router (which knows the difference based on whether any of its interfaces has an address from that net configured).

Comment: IP classes are ancient history and long forgotten.